# Why auto complete does not work for directories in terminal ?

Tags: 13.10, directory, auto-completion

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. While i was using previous versions of Ubuntu, I was able to auto-complete the directories names, even multiple times in a single command. I am not able to the same now. As shown in screen-shot, I am writing this command and then I press Tab. But nothing happens, while I am having a directory at that level , named 'addons'. Can I have solution for this problem I am facing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filepicker autocomplete path stub needs to be separate from any other string. In your example:

```
command --argument=/path/stub<TAB>
```

Bash is just going to see the --argument and bug out. You could probably improve it by making it parse through that but that's not entirely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have the bash auto completion package installed on the system.

```
 sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

Next for Ubuntu 13.10 to enable smart completion, edit your /etc/bash.bashrc file to enable it. Uncomment the following lines, by removing the # in the beginning of the lines:

```
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
# . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

Close your session and re-open it for it to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but its installed ,and running the command again, its says,  bash-completion is already the newest version.

Comment: I've edited the file also but there's no impact. Do i need to restart my system ?

Comment: You should have to reboot but you do need a new bash session after making the change.  Just open a new terminal should be enough.